# Sentence for an advertisement

Tags: grammar

I am designing an advertisement and I've this question now.

Can we say,

> We are now here in New Zealand?

or

> IBM is here in New Zealand?

Which is grammatically correct?

Comment: It is not correct to say 'I was designing a advertisement'. It needs to be 'an advertisement'. Provided you start the sentence with a capital letter there is nothing wrong with either.

Comment: Is the question mark really part of the statement?

Comment: @RegDwigнt, I've edited the question and it is awaiting peer review. Kindly look into the possibility of reopening after my edit reflects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, explaining the edit made by @Rory Alsop.

It should be "an" advertisement and not "a" advertisement. That's because we place "an" before words starting with vowel sounds.

Both the sentences written by you are grammatically correct, however "IBM is here in New Zealand" sounds better to my ears. To add recency you could say "IBM is now in New Zealand"

Comment: your version seems best, the others both sound seriously contrived. Of course this being advertising lingo linguistic correctness is probably less important than being catchy. And for that "IBM is in New Zealand NOW!!!" would likely be best.

Comment: Agreed! Now at the end looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but your choice of which one you use will be down to personal preference.